# Windows form application wont work on another PC

Tags: c#

I created an windows form application that goes to a website and does a HTTPwebrequest POST and then displays the result in a webbrowser. I tested it on the computer that I wrote the program on and it works exactly like it should. However when I get the .exe file from the bin folder along with htmlagilitypack.dll and run a test on another computer, it does the POST data but web page that shows up in broswer is just the default login page. I have looked at it on fiddler and it seems like the cookies aren't getting set to the webbrowser. How can I fix this? I have also compiled the program in release mode and transferred the files in the release folder and its the same result.

On the program I used this to set the cookie for the browser.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);
```

Does it have to do something with that dll file?

Edit: I have made sure both computer has 4.5 NET installed.

```
        //get the cookie first
        CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
        CookieContainer cookiecontainer = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.supremenewyork.com" + url);
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);

        //get the auth token
        using (StreamReader authreader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            source = authreader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        //need the auth token
        string token = Regex.Match(source, "authenticity_token.+?value=\"(.+?)\"").Groups[1].Value;

        //need the POST url
        string action = Regex.Match(source, "UTF-8.+?action=\"(.+?)\"").Groups[1].Value;

        //get the reponse from the server and save the cookies from the first request
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        cookies = response.Cookies;
        response.Close();

        string formparam = string.Format("utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token={0}&size={1}&commit=add to cart", token, sizechart[0]);
        HttpWebRequest webreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.supremenewyork.com"+ action);

        webreq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        webreq.CookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;
        //webreq.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); //recover the cookie first request
        webreq.Method = "POST"; //set a POST method
        webreq.Referer = "http://www.supremenewyork.com" + url;
        webreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";
        webreq.KeepAlive = true;
        webreq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formparam);
        webreq.ContentLength = bytes.Length;


        //write
        Stream postdata = webreq.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
        postdata.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //send the data
        postdata.Close();

        //get the final response from the server
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webreq.GetResponse();
        cookies = resp.Cookies;
        response.Close();
        //Stream answer = resp.GetResponseStream();
        //StreamReader _answer = new StreamReader(webreq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        //string reply = _answer.ReadToEnd();
        //need to check if item has been added to cart
        //richTextBox1.Text = reply;


        //check if item has been added to cart
        HttpWebRequest webreq2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/cart");
        //webreq2.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        webreq2.CookieContainer = webreq.CookieContainer;

        HttpWebResponse resp2 = (HttpWebResponse)webreq2.GetResponse();
        Stream answer2 = resp2.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader _answer2 = new StreamReader(webreq2.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string reply2 = _answer2.ReadToEnd();
        string item = textBoxkeyword.Text;
        string color = textBoxcolor.Text.ToLower();
        if(reply2.Contains(color))
        {
            //proceed to check out

            //update user
            appendtext(nDateTime + item + " " + color + " added to cart" );
            appendtext(nDateTime + "Please check out the item");

            HttpWebRequest webreq3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout");
            //webreq3.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            webreq3.CookieContainer = webreq2.CookieContainer;
            HttpWebResponse resp3 = (HttpWebResponse)webreq3.GetResponse();

            //webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;
            //RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", true);
            //RegKey.SetValue("Display Inline Images", "yes");


            string cookie_string = "";
            foreach (Cookie cook in resp3.Cookies)
            {
                cookie_string += cook.ToString() + ";";
                InternetSetCookie("http://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout", cook.Name, cook.Value);


            }

            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout");

        }
```

Edit2: added all the code

Comment: Show your code that uses `HTTPwebrequest`

Comment: If I understand correctly your project launches a browser instance and makes the request in that browser. Have you confirmed the browser versions are the same? Maybe your third party lib is incompatible with the browser being launched on the second machine and is silently failing to set the cookie.

Comment: I have added the code, It does a httpwebrequest first, then gets the cookie  from the response and adds it to the webbrowser and opens it up.

Comment: You new up 3 separate `CookieContainer` in your code and you are doing other wierd stuff like calling `request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);` but `cookies` is empty at that point. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can demonstarte the issue.

Comment: I commented those lines out. All I did was set each requests cookie container equal to the first requests cookies.